# How to create your own commands in Pyramid 1.4

Tags: python, pyramid, paster

OK, before 1.4 release we had paster where we can add our own commands, for example for drop cache or load database initial data. Right now, how I understand, pyramid deal with Console Scripts but documentation is poor about this new feature.
I want load initial database data. In old-style I write separate command for paster and register it when I will can load data like this:

```
paster loaddbdata
```

How I can do that now?

Comment: When you register a script, it creates an executable in the /bin of your virtualenv. You can read the docs here http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#making-your-script-into-a-console-script and also see the tutorial example here http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/definingmodels.html#changing-scripts-initializedb-py

Comment: @AntoineLeclair. Thanks for your help. But this tutor about pshell (wrapper around python interpreter). And I do it with pshell and so it's looks how you start shell and you have your own command in shell context. It works fine, but I am embarrassed, this is a not proper way to load initial data I think. Can I do this through setup.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyramid provides the `pyramid.paster.bootstrap()` to make it easy to create a script with your application. Turning a script into a command isn't done through any complicated construct provided by Pyramid, but rather you should just use setuptools entry points. This involves adding a `[console_scripts]` section to your `setup.py` `entry_points`, re-running develop, and your script should be installed into the `bin` directory.

```
setup(
   # ...
   entry_points={
    'paste.app_factory': [
        'main = myapp:main',
    ],
    'console_scripts': [
        'myscript = myapp.scripts.myscript:main',
    ],
)
```